# how to attach new function go javascript

Tags: javascript

i have this script

```
<body>
    <input id='input' />
</body>

function addEvent(element, eventName, callback){
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
    }          
}

function simas_slider(bodyObj){
    this.left = 0;
    addEvent(bodyObj,'mousemove',(function(slider){
        return function(e){
            slider.left = e.clientX;
        }
    })(this));
    this.onchange: ???
}

var slider = new simas_slider(document.body);
slider.onchange = function(currPoss){ // currposs is object slider left
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.value = currPoss;
}
```

how to add function onchage to object simas_slider?
so i need whenever value in slider is changed, the value inside input will be changed also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
    }
}

function simas_slider(bodyObj) {
    this.left = 0;
    this.onchange = function () {};

    addEvent(bodyObj, 'mousemove', (function (slider) {
        return function (e) {
            slider.left = e.clientX;
            slider.onchange(slider.left);
        }
    })(this));
}

var slider = new simas_slider(document.body);
slider.onchange = function (currPoss) {
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.value = currPoss;
};
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/tdwbw38p/1/**

Comment: why you can do this and it's work very well? i still cannot understand yet :)
you do awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have everything you need. All you need to do is call `onchange` when the value of `slider.left` is changed:

```
slider.left = e.clientX;
slider.onchange(slider.left);
```

or if you want to be careful

```
slider.left = e.clientX;
if (typeof slider.onchange === 'function') {
    slider.onchange(slider.left);
}
```